# Del Operator in Cylindrical and Spherical Co-ordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The del operator in cartesian co-ordinates are defined as:

$$\nabla =\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\hat x+\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\hat y+\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\hat z$$

I'm trying to derive the form in cylindrical and spherical co-ordinates.

I know for cylindrical co-ordinates: $$\ x=\rho cos\phi
                                       \\ y=\rho sin\phi
                                       \\ z=z$$
where $\rho$ is the radius of the cylinder and $\phi$ is the angle between the vector and the X-axis.

and I also know for spherical co-ordinates:$$\ x=r sin\theta cos\phi
                                       \\ y=r sin\theta sin\phi
                                       \\ z=r cos\theta$$

where $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $\phi$ is the angle between the vector and the X-axis and $\theta$ is the angle between the vector and the Z-axis.

Can I use the chain rule to derive it?

I know I can google the formulas, but deriving them makes it easier to remember and recollect.

I'm not looking for an entire solution just want to know where I can start with the derivation.

Comment: That is not a $\nabla$, it must be a vector. Is this what you mean?

Comment: $\nabla$ is the del operator but  i guess I forgot the unit vectors

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840286/gradient-divergence-curl-in-orthogonal-curvelinear-cordinates, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195970/where-does-the-formula-for-gradient-and-divergence-come-for-curvilinear-systems, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784137/prove-the-formula-of-gradient-in-cylindrical-coordinates, etc.